# slideToggle state not working with multiple boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to save the toggle state of collapsable boxes using cookies. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="box_container">
    <div class="box_handle">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="box" data-title="admin_actions">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('div.box_container div.box_handle').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.box').slideToggle('fast');
});
$.each($('div.box_container div.box_handle'), function(index,value){
    if ($.cookie('show_box_' + $(value).next('.box').attr('data-title')) != 'closed'){
        $(value).next('.box[data-title="' + $('.box').attr('data-title') + '"]').hide();
    }
});
var new_value = "";
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.each($('div.box_container div.box_handle'),function(index,value){
        new_value = ($(value).next('.box').css('display') == 'none') ? 'open' : 'closed';
        $.cookie('show_box_' + $(value).next('.box').attr('data-title'), new_value);
    });
}
```

Now, my problem is:

Any boxes other than the first one will always appear opened. It does set a cookie for it, but does not hide it if cookie is set to `closed` Only for each first box on a page it works. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `onbeforeunload` function of javascript

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      //Declare cookie to close state
 }
```

This function will be called every time page refreshes

Update:

To make loop through every value use this `$.each` this way:

```
var new_value = "";
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 $.each($('div.box_container div.box_handle'),function(index,value){
  new_value = ($(value).next('.box').css('display') == 'none') ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded';
  $.cookie('show_box' + '_' + $(value).next('.box').attr('data-title'), new_value);
 })
}
```

Update II :

Do this, it should work

```
window.onload = checkCon;
function checkCon(){
 $.each($('div.box_container div.box_handle'),function(index,value){
  if ($.cookie('show_box' + '_' + $(value).next('.box').attr('data-title')) != 'expanded'){
   $(value).next('.box[data-title="' + $(value).next('.box').attr('data-title') + '"]').hide();
  }
 })
}
```

Comment: Nice, that worked like a charm! However, it still only works for each first box on the page. Any idea how I can get the code to work for all boxes? I'll update my question and code.

Comment: It now sets the cookies correctly, thanks! However, it still only actually opens/closes the first box on the page. Can I use the $.each in my if-statement as well to make every box open/close correctly?

Comment: I already tried wrapping `.each()` around the if-statement. Unfortunately, it does not work and neither does your code.

Comment: It should work you are writing the come in `window.load` or `document.ready(callback)` ryt

Comment: The entire code is within `$document.ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: I have changed the code please try and tell me if it works.